# Parse Android: subscribe/unsubscribe not really coherent with online

Tags: android, parse-platform

We are using Parse for our android client and have a problem with cache.

Each device has a unique channel that they register. If I go in online and remove the channel in Data Browser the device still thinks its already registered. If I call subscribe for the channel it seems like this call is not made and my guess is that it checks a local cache and since this say its already registered it will make this call.

If i call this method PushService.getSubscriptions it will give me a list of channels that is not coherent to whats online. Somewhere it say that PushService.getSubscriptions is cached locally and this is really strange?

So I then tried to do something like this to make sure its always update to date:

```
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, null);
    Set<String> channels = PushService.getSubscriptions(_context);
    for(String channel : channels){
        PushService.unsubscribe(this, channel);
    }
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, RD4MainV4Activity.class);
    PushService.subscribe(this, licenseKeyValue, RD4MainV4Activity.class);
```

But then I get error. And I have tried doing these in different orders etc but I get in to issues whatever I do.

```
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Operation is invalid after previous operation.
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.PushRouter$8$1.run(PushRouter.java:235)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Operation is invalid after previous operation.
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.ParseAddUniqueOperation.apply(ParseAddUniqueOperation.java:96)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.ParseObject.performOperation(ParseObject.java:2734)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.ParseObject.addAllUnique(ParseObject.java:2850)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.ParseObject.addUnique(ParseObject.java:2835)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.PushRouter.subscribe(PushRouter.java:618)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.PushRouter$1.then(PushRouter.java:72)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.PushRouter$1.then(PushRouter.java:69)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:448)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:444)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:318)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:329)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.Task$8.then(Task.java:381)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.Task$8.then(Task.java:373)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-03 17:13:45.494: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

My dream senario would be that I can get the Online version for the device. And then just check if its correct and fix this if the channel is missing or if a wrong channel is registered to the device.

Can I check this in any way?

Comment: I have now tried a lot of things like ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().refresh(); and ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().fetch(); I can see that they download the list but they do not remove channels that are wrong. Unregister is also only removing things that are online. So if I have more in my local list and they are not online it works but cant remove them if they are online.

Comment: have you managed to figure this out? I'm having similar issues...

Answer (score 2):

I've run into a similar issue but was able to solve it with a little bit of a hack.

With the current version of Parse (1.9.2 as of this writing), the way that you subscribe to channels is with ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(channelname). This method atomically adds the string "channelname" to the String array called "channels" in the user's installation object but, for me anyway, threw the same error given above:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Operation is invalid after previous operation.
```

The way that I was able to solve this issue was by writing my own version of subscribeInBackground, which goes something like:

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().put("channels",
                Arrays.asList(new String[]{
                        "channelname"
                }));
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

To unsubscribe, just perform the reverse operation:

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().put("channels",
                Arrays.asList(new String[]{})); //Put the empty list to unsubcribe!
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

This relies on you to manage your channel array, but doesn't crash inexplicably.